# Assign random value to a variable at compile time

Tags: vb.net

My code has a Public variable whose value I want to change every time I compile the Solution. How can I do?

This is actual declaration:
`Public AppCode as String = "AABBCCDDEEFFGGHHII"`

What I am looking for is something like this, but at compile time:
`AppCode = Guid.NewGuid().ToString`

Thank you
Danny

Comment: I'll post this as a comment rather than an answer because I can't provide specific details. You should post your own answer once you work out those details. You should write a batch file that will edit your code as required. Probably the simplest option would be to isolate that field in its own file and simply rewrite the whole thing each time. You can then run that batch file using the [pre-build event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/pre-build-event-post-build-event-command-line-dialog-box?view=vs-2022) in VS.

Comment: You can access that event's commandline from the Compile page of the project properties.

Comment: Thanks @jmcilhinney, I'll study prebuild-event.